# user input date format verification in bash

Tags: bash, validation, date

So I'm trying to write a simple script in bash that asks user for input date in 
following format (YYYY-dd-mm). Unfortunately I got stuck on first step, which is verifying that input is in correct format. I tried using 'date' with no luck (as it returns actual current date). I'm trying to make this as simple as possible. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using regex:

```
if [[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-3][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]$ ]]; then
```

or with bash globs:

```
if [[ $date == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-1][0-9] ]]; then
```

Please note that this regex will accept a date like `9999-00-19` which is not a correct date. So after you check its possible correctness with this regex you should verify that the numbers are correct.

```
IFS='-' read -r year day month <<< "$date"
```

This will put the numbers into `$year` `$day` and `$month` variables.

Comment: Perfect, it does exactly what it is supposed to! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
date -d "$date" +%Y-%m-%d
```

The latter is the format, the -d allows an input date. If it's wrong it will return an error that can be piped to the bit bucket, if it's correct it will return the date.

The format modifiers can be found in the manpage of date `man 1 date`. Here an example with an array of 3 dates:

```
dates=(2012-01-34 2014-01-01 2015-12-24)

for Date in ${dates[@]} ; do
    if [ -z "$(date -d $Date 2>/dev/null)" ; then
       echo "Date $Date is invalid"
    else
       echo "Date $Date is valid"
    fi
done
```

Just a note of caution: typing `man date` into Google while at work can produce some NSFW results ;)